# Why does depolarising channel shrinks Bloch vectors?

Tags: depolarizing-channel

Let's start with

$Tr_{\Omega}[U|0,\Omega_{0}\rangle\langle0,\Omega_{0}|U^{\dagger}] = \sum_{\alpha}E_{\alpha}|0\rangle\langle0|E_{\alpha}^{\dagger}$
where $U$ be a unitary operator. The trace operator traces out $|\Omega\rangle$

$U|0,\Omega_{0}\rangle = \sqrt{p}|0,\Omega_{0}\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{1-p}{3}}\bigg(X|0,\Omega_{1}\rangle + Z|0,\Omega_{2}\rangle + Y|0,\Omega_{3}\rangle\bigg)$

In density operator, this is:

$\rho = p|0,\Omega_{0}\rangle\langle0,\Omega_{0}| + \frac{1-p}{3}\bigg(X|0,\Omega_{1}\rangle\langle0,\Omega_{1}| + Y|0,\Omega_{3}\rangle\langle0,\Omega_{3}| + Z|0,\Omega_{2}\rangle\langle0,\Omega_{2}|\bigg)$

**Why does a depolarising channel shrinks a Bloch vector $\vec{n}$ to $\frac{4p-1}{3}\vec
{n}$?**

Below [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyBWq.png)
[image: 1]

I took a look at [2]:

A density matrix $\rho$ after undergoing a depolarising channel is $\epsilon(\rho, p) = \frac{pI}{2} + (1-p)\rho$ so that $\epsilon(\rho, p=\frac{1}{2}) = \frac{1}{2}I + \frac{1}{4}\vec{n}\vec{\sigma}$.

Now, the definition for density matrix $\rho$ in terms of Bloch vector $\vec{n}$ is $\frac{1}{2}[I + \vec{n}\vec{\sigma}]$.

As can be seen, the factor of the Bloch vector goes from $\frac{1}{2}$ to $\frac{1}{4}$. If $p = 0$, the Bloch vector $\vec{n}$ remains unchanged as the factor of $\frac{1}{2}$ remains.

It does appears as thought the probability $p$ for which $\rho$ is depolarised is related to the shrinkage factor of $\vec{n}$ upon depolarisation.

[[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyBWq.png)] Depolarising channel definition from notes

[2] page 378, Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Nielson and Chang

Comment: Where did you get this definition of a depolarising channel from?

Comment: @DaftWullie I obtained it from notes

Comment: "from notes" doesn't tell me much if I want to follow it up. For example, are you told that the states $|\Omega_i\rangle$ are orthogonal? (I don't know if you need that, but wouldn't be surprised if you did.) Also, why do you write $\text{Tr}_{\Omega}(|0,\Omega_0\rangle\langle 0,\Omega_0|U^\dagger)$ and not $\text{Tr}_{\Omega}(U|0,\Omega_0\rangle\langle 0,\Omega_0|U^\dagger)$?

Comment: @DaftWullie That was a typo. And yes, they are orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't really make much sense to do this calculation just with an input state $|0\rangle$. So, instead, I'll replace $|0\rangle$ with $|\psi\rangle$.

If you calculate $\text{Tr}_\Omega\rho$, you'll get
$$
\text{Tr}_\Omega\rho=p|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|+\frac{p}{3}(X|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|X+Y|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|Y+Z|\psi\rangle\langle \psi|Z).
$$
It's possibly easiest to think about how the Bloch vector changes. If $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ has Bloch vector $(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)$, then a term such as $X|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|X$ has Bloch vector $(n_X,-n_Y,-n_Z)$. Also, if I add two density matrices together, that's equivalent to adding their Bloch vectors together. So, overall, I have a new Bloch vector
$$
p(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)+\frac{1-p}{3}((n_X,-n_Y,-n_Z)+(-n_X,n_Y,-n_Z)+(-n_X,-n_Y,n_Z))
$$
which is the same as
$$
\left(p-\frac{1-p}{3}\right)(n_X,n_Y,n_Z)
$$

Comment: This is nice. Could I request for you to provide an explicit but arbitrary example of the effects of $X|\psi\rangle\langle|X$ on the Bloch vector?

Comment: How do you express $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|$ in terms of the Bloch vector? What are the commutation relations of Paulis? (e.g. what is $XZX$?)

Comment: $|\psi\rangle\langle\psi| = \frac{1}{4}[I \otimes I + ... + \hat{n}\vec{\sigma} \otimes 
 \hat{m} \vec{\sigma}]$

Comment: I'm not sure your point.

Comment: The effect of the operation $X|\psi\rangle\langle\psi|X \equiv X \rho X$ on the bloch sphere is that the whole bloch sphere rotates around $X$-axis by $\pi$. However, the effect of a bit-flip map, say $\Phi$, $$\Phi(\rho) = p\rho + (1-p) X \rho X $$ is that the Bloch sphere becomes a rugby ball-like shape,  an ellipsoid with the long axis being the $X$-axis. You can read about it more in the chapter $\text{VII}$ of [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1902.00967.pdf).

Comment: @Physkid My point is that I'm trying to help you answer your own question instead of me doing it for you! (by the way, you've given a version for a two-qubit state. I meant a one-qubit state)

Comment: @DaftWullie I understand you're helping - my apologises if I came across as terse. The one qubit Density matrix is $\rho = \frac{1} {2}[I + \vec{n}\vec{\sigma} ]$.

Comment: @FDGod yes, X is equal to a $R_{x}(\frac{\theta} {2} ) $ for $\theta =\pi$ up to global phase. My geometric understanding is that this is a rotation about the X axis by $\theta$ which means I expect the flipping to apply to all axis except for the x axis.

Comment: In applying X to $\rho$, X is applied to $\vec{n} $ so based on the notion of rotation operator about x axis above, if my understanding is sufficient, flips the y and z components of the Bloch vector so that $X\vec{n} = (nx, - ny, - nz) = n'$. But what does $n'X$ describes? @FDGod

Comment: You cannot directly apply the Pauli operator to the Bloch vector. You apply it to the state. $X\rho X=X\frac12[I+\vec{n}\cdot\vec{\sigma}]X=X(I+n_XX+n_YY+n_ZZ)X/2$. So now you just perform the multiplications (commutation properties help a lot) and find for the coefficients in front of the Pauli matrices change.

Comment: @DaftWullie I got it!

Comment: @DaftWullie I have a question relating to the physical description:

In comparing the Bloch vector, it appears we are comparing $\rho = \frac{1}{2}[I + \vec{n}\vec{\sigma}]$ with $\rho^{\psi} = Tr_{\Omega}[\rho_{DC}]$ rather than with $\rho_{DC} = U|\psi, \Omega\rangle\langle\psi,\Omega|U$. Why is this so? my understanding is that upon application of $U$, the Bloch vector shrinks so there is no need for the Trace operator.

Comment: The Bloch vector is primarily appropriate to a single qubit. You need the partial trace operation to get a description of just that single qubit.